# Why is importing not working in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to import my second file into App.js for my project. I am getting the error "The development server returned response error code: 500". Basically saying "Unable to resolve "MainFile" from "App.js".

Why is this happening? I believe it is correct but for some reason this bugfest saying that the file doesn't exist. First code is my App.js file and the second one is the code i am trying to import.

https://gyazo.com/6911c477f9c9e8149370571ca49a0b9f

https://gyazo.com/73f0079bc6a2640877bcc30fa1e609ec

```
import React from 'react';
import MainFile from './components/MainFile';


export default class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <MainFile />
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class MainFile extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Testing</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {

    },
});
```

Comment: Can you add file directory as screenshot ? because its looks like you are importing from wrong  place.

Comment: Oki sure! added two screenshots. I tried with './testapp/components/MainFile' aswell but that didnt work either. Also tried having the MainFile.js outside components aswell

Comment: without importing MainFile app is working ?

Comment: Yep it does !..

Comment: İnteresting. Did you tried to restart metro bundler ?

Comment: Ye i tried that aswell. Is native react really this buggy?

Comment: nope. its very simple thing. I didnt get it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. delete node_modules folder
2. edit package json : react-native version to "55.4" or "55.2" and
   babel-preset-react-native to "4.0.0" ( if your version is different
   try to use the latest one or downgrade it).
3. run npm install or yarn install command
4. you're done

Source : [Github](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/401#issuecomment-414155454)

Answer (score 1):

1. Double check if file exist at given path or not
2. If file is not javascript(.js), then mention the extension
3. Try using double quote when referring to file ( e.g. "./src/..")
4. If file to import is not .js, then make sure appropriate react library is imported in first import
   E.g.( import {..., Image } from 'react-native' )

Answer (score 0):

In my situation i changed ./MainFile to ./MainFile.js and it start worked. this should work without specifying extension. But something went wrong and he needed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an index.js or ts page in the folder from which you are importing components and then write an export statement for component in that index.js page.

add export just like follows then import should work -

export { default as Home } from './Home'

Answer (score 0):

This answer did not work on my project because I use a much newer release than this one.

I use this type of export in the component:

```
export default componentName
```

In that case, I have to import it without curly braces

```
import componentName from './file' //ok
import { componentName } from './file' //wrong!
```

[Source](https://blog.logrocket.com/troubleshooting-common-react-native-bugs/#import-error)